# Autenticação com duas tabelas diferentes

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-auth

Eu preciso fazer duas autenticações, uma para clientes outra para administradores, então tenho que ter duas instância de auth; como fazer isso no Laravel, sendo que eu tenho uma tabela de cliente e outra de administradores?

Comment: porque é que tem 2 tabelas?

Comment: uma de clientes e outra de administradores.

Comment: Acredito que o ideal é você criar uma tabela específica para login, a qual será "linkada" ou com  clientes ou com administradores (especialização).

Assim fica melhor até de trabalhar, pois imagine que em uma tabela o nome do usuario o campo correspondente é 'nome', e em outra 'nome_completo', você terá que encher o seu sistema de if (ou então criar acessors, mas mesmo assim).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O método mais prático é configurar a autenticação na rota onde se fizer necessário:

```php
Config::set('auth.model', 'Admin');
```

ou ainda, setar para um padrão de URI's

```php
if ($request->is('admin*'))
{
    Config::set('auth.model', 'Admin');
}
```

Desse modo, o Model `Admin` será responsável pela autenticação.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que seja o caso de se criar uma nova classe do Auth `Illuminate\Auth\Guard` e algumas Facades, pra replicar o componente Auth. Aí você faria, por exemplo, uma autenticação usando `Auth::attempt()` e outra usando a sua autenticação, `MeuAuth::attempt()`.