# Como lidar com múltiplas áreas de logins no Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-auth, auth

Em minha aplicação tenho 3 áreas distintas:

**Admin**

> Onde tudo é gerenciado, atualmente a autentificação é feita pelo Sentry (muito bom por sinal). Para esta área tenho o model Users que faz a comunicação com o banco de dados.

**Alunos**

> Onde o aluno tem acesso a uma grande gama de dados e ferramentas.

**Responsáveis**

> Onde o responsável do aluno entra para gerenciar seus pagamentos e dados.

Cada uma delas possui sua própria model/tabela e formato

Realmente não estou conseguindo imaginar como resolver esse problema.

Comment: Qual problema exatamente? A autenticação em si com múltiplos models? Neste caso, a pergunta parece mesmo duplicada, como apontou o hernandes.

Comment: Realmente é isso, eu não havia encontrado essa pergunta antes, por isso resolvi posta-la.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O método mais prático é configurar a autenticação na rota onde se fizer necessário:

```php
Config::set('auth.model', 'Admin');
```

ou ainda, setar para um padrão de URI's

```php
if ($request->is('admin*'))
{
    Config::set('auth.model', 'Admin');
}
```

Desse modo, o Model `Admin` será responsável pela autenticação.

P.S. respondi com a mesma resposta de [Autenticação com duas tabelas diferentes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1925/autenticacao-com-duas-tabelas-diferentes) e estou votando como duplicata.

Comment: Com esse método você muda o modo de autenticação no momento em que se autentica, então nas requisições seguintes, pois ele retorna ao modelo normal, isso deve ser mantido de alguma forma (Sugiro Sessão)

Comment: Gostei da alternativa @hernandes eu uso um filtro antes das minhas rotas protegidas.

Acho que posso colocar esse comando lá mesmo.

Comment: Hernandes, você já utilizou este método?
Pois após Logar o config::get('auth.model') volta a ser o "USER" então quanto o usuário der Auth::user() irá dar erro não?

Comment: @FlávioH.Ferreira a configuração volta ao padrão a cada requisição, você deve setar na mesma requisição antes de usar o Auth:user

Comment: sim... mas a cada nova requisição você deve setar novamente o Config::set('auth.model', 'Admin'); para que não dê problema.

Comment: extamente, as configurações setadas "on-the-fly" não persistem, uma boa prática seria setá-la no construct do Controller ou cria uma método config e chama-lo em cada método do controller